# Gatling print to file if KO

Tags: scala, gatling

I have an .exec which for some values in my parameter list results in KO (value does not exists in the SUT). 
I further have the need to print these values to a file so I later can remove them from the parameter list in order to not get KO`s.
I have a writer defined

```
 val writer = {
val fos = new java.io.FileOutputStream("testresultater.txt")
new java.io.PrintWriter(fos,true)
```

}

and wonder how I could do this just for KO`s inside the .exec resulting in KO`s for some values like this:

```
.exec(http("request_lagDokument")
        .post("/proxy/dokumenter/api/v1/SaveDokumentFil?IsDebug=true")
        .headers(headers_3)
        .body(ElFileBody("magnus/LagDokument.json"))
        .check(status.is(expected = 200))
        .check(jsonPath("$.DokumentGuid").saveAs("DokumentGuid")))


//if KO then:

    .exec((s: Session) => {
        writer.println(s.attributes("pnr"))
        s
    })
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by having a session function that is always executed with the conditional logic inside

```
.exec(session = {
  if (session.isFailed) {
    writer.println(s.attributes("pnr"))
  }
  session
})
```

or you can use the dsl's doIf

```
.doIf(session => session.isFailed) {
  exec(session => {
    writer.println(s.attributes("pnr"))
    session
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, but given the current .exec
 
  .exec(http("request_lagDokument")
  .post("/proxy/dokumenter/api/v1/SaveDokumentFil?IsDebug=true")
  .headers(headers_3)
  .body(ElFileBody("magnus/LagDokument.json"))
  .check(status.is(expected = 200))
  .check(jsonPath("$.DokumentGuid").saveAs("DokumentGuid")) 
  )
Where do I put the 

 if (session.isFailed) {
    writer.println(s.attributes("pnr"))
  }

?

Comment: it will have to be in a following exec block - so the one I posted in the answer should follow the exec with the post

Comment: I tried this:

.exec((s: Session) => {
   http("request_lagDokument")
    .post("/proxy/dokumenter/api/v1/SaveDokumentFil?IsDebug=true")
    .headers(headers_3)
    .body(ElFileBody("magnus/LagDokument.json"))
    .check(status.is(expected = 200))
    .check(jsonPath("$.DokumentGuid").saveAs("DokumentGuid"))
   if (s.isFailed) {
    writer.println(s.attributes("pnr"))
   }
   s
  })

But hen the entire .exec is not executed at all.

Comment: that won't work - you can't have gatling dsl statements inside a session function. The dsl defines builders that are created once at startup and if you try to create them during a run, nothing will happen.